# php regex and or ( | )

Tags: php, regex

I am experimenting a problem with | (or) and the regex in php.

Here is what I would like to do, for example I have those 3 sentences :

"apple is good to eat"

"an apple a day keeps the doctor away"

"i like to eat apple"

And lets say that i would like to change the word apple by orange, so here is my code :

```
$oldWord="apple";
$newWord="orange";
$text = preg_replace('#^' . $oldWord . ' #', $newWord, $text);
$text = preg_replace('# ' . $oldWord . ' #', $newWord, $text);
$text = preg_replace('# ' . $oldWord . '$#', $newWord, $text);
```

Of course it works but i haven't found the right combinaison to do that with only one line of code with the key word | (or).

Do you guys have any suggestion please ? thanks

Comment: `"Of course it works"`? preg_match won't replace anything.

Comment: So in other words, `$oldWord` can be *anywhere*? Why use `^` and `$` at all then?

Comment: I am guessing you are doing this to prevent matches where "apple" is only part of a word, as in "Snapple"? If so, you may want [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): `#\bapple\b#`

Comment: sorry i made a mistake with preg_replace, gonna edit my post thanks

Comment: thanks Wiseguy do you please know the syntax for the same thing but for a variable instead of apple ?

Comment: Note that your code swallows the spaces on either side of the target word. For instance, running your code with `$text = 'An apple a day'` yields `'Anorangea day'`. Do you want to preserve spaces?

Comment: It would help if you showed the results you are getting, and the results you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your regex removes the spaces around `apple`. If this is not what you desire, but instead you just want to replace `apple` if it's the full word, then, as some others recommended, use word boundaries:

```
$text = preg_replace('#\b' . $oldWord . '\b#', $newWord, $text);
```

If you **did** intent to remove the spaces, too you could require a wordboundary, but make the spaces optional:

```
$text = preg_replace('#[ ]?\b' . $oldWord . '\b[ ]?#', $newWord, $text);
```

If they are there, they will be removed, too. If they are not, the regex doesn't care. Note that `[ ]` is completely equivalent to just typing a space, but I find it more readable in a regex.

Comment: Won't match the string `"apple"` though. This requires it to have spaces either side.

Comment: @nickf sorry, totally overlooked those

Comment: now it will match in `"pineapple"` which I guess is not desired by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `str_replace('apple', 'orange', $text);`?

## EDIT:

Per comment from user:

```
preg_replace('/\bapple\b/', 'orange', $text);
```

If you're concerned about properly escaping the search word in the expression:

```
$oldWord = preg_quote($oldWord, '/');
$text = preg_replace("/\b$oldWord\b/", $newWord, $text);
```

Comment: because i only want to remove 'apple' if it is alone, for example i don't want to remove 'anapple'

Answer (score 1):

So, if you want to replace the **whole word only**, that is, leave "pineapple" alone, then the `str_replace` method won't work. What you should be using is the word boundary anchor `\b`

```
preg_replace('#\b' + $oldWord + '\b#', $newWord, $text)
```

Comment: thanks i tried but i got the error    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

Comment: @user1836529 o_o  add a semicolon then? `$text = preg_replace('#\b' + $oldWord + '\b#\, $newWord, text);`

Answer (score 0):

simply use `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match`

```
preg_replace('⁓\b'.$oldWord.'\b⁓', $newWord, $text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test but

```
$text = preg_match('#\b' . $oldWord . '\b#ig', $newWord, $text);
```

Shoudl save your day ;)

Comment: Nice copy / paste from the comment section ;-)

Comment: @peeHaa, you know, I answered 10 minutes ago, similar comment where posted two minutes later... are you sure I copied it?

Comment: @user1836529 leave it out. `preg_replace` is global by default